# C# '|' operator and arguments

Tags: c#, powershell, operators, or-operator

I'm rewriting a C# script in PowerShell, and I've hit another roadblock.

I'm pretty sure `|` is the `or` operator for C#.

Does this code mean get methods of this name with either an instance, public or nonpublic binding flag?

How off am I?

My end goal is to implement something similar into PowerShell. So, how can I do something similar in PowerShell?

```
type.GetMethod(Name, [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::Instance | [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::Public | [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::NonPublic)
```

Comment: `||` is the logical or operator. `|` is bitwise or. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/operators

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `|` is the (bitwise) OR operator in C#. In PowerShell, however, `|` is the "pipe" operator to connect the output of one cmdlet to the input of another. The binary OR operator in PowerShell is `-bor`.

Also see [`about_Operators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0).